# CountIf on two files

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have two files and both have an ID or identifier that share the same value.

I need to open the first file and run countif function to do the following:

1. Read cells values in a specific columns from file 1.
2. Go to file 2 and run countif function to see how many values are exist in file 2 that matches the cells in file 1.
3. come back to file 1 and print the results next to each cell in file 1.

I am able to run countif for only one cell. I can't find how I can use this function to open another file and look for an item and come back to print out inside the first one.

Comment: A formula will not open another file.  You will need to do it manually or use vba.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually:

In the other file, use a helper sheet or a helper column to perform the CountIF in that workbook.

In the first file, use a simple cell reference to the other file's helper cells.

The CountIF in the second file will either be recalculated on the fly if it is open, or, if it is closed, it will return the latest stored result of the CountIF.

Comment: Awesome, I will try this approach and let you know. 

Thanks a lot